# MySQL How do i find duplicates of column that have different value in specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that consists of:

```
ID|NAME|KEY
0 |A   |0x00 OK
1 |B   |0x01 OK
2 |A   |0x03 <<< DUP with different KEY 
3 |A   |0x00 OK
4 |A   |0x00 OK
```

As you see, I have duplicates of "A" but only one of them is having a different key.
I am looking to find them in the data with a MySQL Query.

What would be the query to get duplicates of NAME which have different KEYS ?

In other words:

Looking to find DUPLICATED NAMES only if their KEYs differ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

- This will give you all unique name, key combinations by grouping them on columns name and key.
- This works by creating N level groups which in our case translates to N = 2 meaning 1st level groups on name and 2nd level group on keys.
- Demo here -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4KjTdq5p9SEh94BThMdPg/6

```
with a as (
  select distinct name, my_key
  from some_table
)
select * from a
where name in (
  select name 
  from a 
  group by name 
  having count(1) > 1
)
group by name, my_key;
```

Comment: This will return ALL grouped by NAME,KEY
I want only the ones that are duplicated and have different keys.

Comment: @PeeS can you add expected output from your sample data, i can try and update the answer accordingly + also the criteria on which basis you would say which one is duplicate amongst N entries.

Comment: Name|Key |
----+----+
A   |0x00|
A   |0x03|
B   |0x01|

Comment: @PeeS as per your expected result, the answer would work as required, check the demo link.

Comment: the output still displays "B" which is not duplicated. Please see my question, i am looking to find DUPLICATED NAMES only if their KEYs are different

Comment: @PeeS your comment above includes "B".

Comment: which is wrong, according to the question.
We need to find "A" as only this one is DUPLICATED and has different KEY.

Comment: @Pees i am confused as to what is required, but i've updated the answer, check that.

Comment: Thanks, but it still shows "B" where it shouldnt. - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4KjTdq5p9SEh94BThMdPg/3

It shouldnt because B is not DUPLICATED with DIFFERENT key

Comment: @Pees check updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
select name, my_key 
from some_table 
where name in (select name from some_table group by name having count(1)>1) 
AND my_key not in (select my_key from some_table group by my_key having count(1)>
group by name, my_key;
```

Test here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4KjTdq5p9SEh94BThMdPg/5

Comment: There is no need to `group by name, my_key` since you want my_key to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `COUNT()` window function separately for `name` and `my_key` and filter based on their results:

```
SELECT name, my_key
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) count_name,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY my_key) count_key
  FROM some_table 
) t
WHERE count_name > 1 AND count_key = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4KjTdq5p9SEh94BThMdPg/7).

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = 'A' AND `key` != '0x00'
```

Comment: No, in that case i would have to provide keys myself.